# Elliptical marquee selection then fill with color in Photoshop using Javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Basically what I am trying to do is create dots on specifics location. Dots needs to be placed on 1/3 of each end of the upper part of the image and then one on the center.

Using brush tool will also work, but I can't seem to find any reference on how to set the coordinates of where the brush will be used.

So far I was only able to figure out how to fill the selection

```
function fillSelection()
{
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var dotColor = new SolidColor;
    dotColor.rgb.hexValue = '000000';
    var newLayer = doc.artLayers.add();
    doc.selection.fill(dotColor);
    doc.selection.deselect();
}
```

This is how it is supposed to look like:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbor0.jpg)

As you can see I'm not an expert at this so your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a selection for your dots with this:

```
function selectIt(top, left, right, bottom)
{
    var id1 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id2 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    var id3 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    var id4 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
    ref1.putProperty( id3, id4 );
    desc1.putReference( id2, ref1 );
    var id5 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id6 = charIDToTypeID( "Top " );
    var id7 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id6, id7, top ); //top
    var id8 = charIDToTypeID( "Left" );
    var id9 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id8, id9, left ); //left
    var id10 = charIDToTypeID( "Btom" );
    var id11 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id10, id11, bottom ); //bottom
    var id12 = charIDToTypeID( "Rght" );
    var id13 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id12, id13, right ); //right

    var id14 = charIDToTypeID( "Elps" );
    desc1.putObject( id5, id14, desc2 );
    var id15 = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );
    desc1.putBoolean( id15, true );

    executeAction( id1, desc1, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

You'll probably want to modify the above function and just supply X, Y & radius parameters to the function instead of the limits of the ellipse (top, bottom, left right).

Also it might be worth putting an extra deselection at the start of the function just in case you have something already selected. ;)